# Is there a way to change the prototype from within a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this type of code for prototypal inheritance in Javascript.

```
function A() {
    this.a = 1;
}
function B() {
    someEl.innerHTML(this.a);
}
B.prototype = new A();
```

However, I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, preferably one that brings the prototype declaration into the declaration of `B`.

I tried setting `this.prototype` in `B`, but it just showed `this.a` as `undefined`.

So, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `prototype` property should be used only in [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function), `this.prototype` doesn't makes sense because `this` just the new object instance, not the constructor.

Assign the `prototype` inside the constructor itself isn't a good idea, since that assignment will be executed each time you create a new object (by `new B();`).

Your code seems perfectly valid to me, the only thing that you should be aware of, is that if you replace the `prototype` property of a constructor, like you do it with `B.prototype = new A();` the `constructor` property of the object instances of `B`, will point to `A`.

Usually is recommended to restore that property, e.g.:

```
function A() {
    this.a = 1;
}

function B() {
    someEl.innerHTML(this.a);
}

B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B; // restore the `constructor` property

var foo = new B;
foo.constructor === B; // true
```

Give a look to:

- [Constructors considered mildly confusing](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html) (article)
- [Setting javascript prototype function within object class declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784844/setting-javascript-prototype-function-within-object-class-declaration) (SO question)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function A() {
    this.a = 1;
}
function B() {
    this.prototype = new A();
    someEl.innerHTML(this.A.a); //notice A.a
}
```

Comment: That works, but given that it means distinguishing between prototype inherited variables, and it's own members, it's probably a cure worse than the problem (a declaration outside the function).

Comment: I do not know any other way of doing something like that. It is not possible to set a function's prototype before it is declared. The method you currently use is the "by-the-book" way.

Comment: Assigning `this.prototype` doesn't makes sense, the `prototype` property should be used on [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function), the `this` value is simply a new object instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyClass() {
    this.initialize();
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {               // adding a function name
        this.some_var = "Blue";            // makes debugging easier
    },
    tell_color: function() {
        alert(this.color);
    },
    color: "red"
}

var instance = new MyClass();
instance.tell_color();
```

This wasn't my idea, but I don't know anymore where I've found it.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance in JS is a little weird, but everyone else is correct that you should never put a prototype within a constructor.  The point of prototyped functions/vars is so you only have a singular instance of that function for ALL instances of said class to use.  Likewise it is good for class vars, a singular value which every instance will reference.

Really, you should make class B inherit from class A:

```
function B(){
     this.object = new A();
}

B.prototype.a = function(){
     return object.a;
}
```

which can be a little annoying since you must then create new getters/setters, buuuuuuuttttt, if you are feeling a little adventurous, you can build something like this......

```
function breakApart(what){
     var functions = [];
     var properties = [];

     for(property in what){
         if(typeof what[property] == 'function'){
             functions.push({'name':property,'value':what[property]});
         }else{           
             properties.push({'name':property,'value':what[property]});
         }
     }

     var data = [
         {'title':'functions','data':functions},
         {'title':'properties', 'data':properties}
         ];

     return data;
}
```

Add a few eval() calls and some logic and you can make this function build you new getters/setters/function references.