# Use Object method in anthor object without using new keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two constructor function, I just want to use object `a` method in object `b` without using `new` keyword because I dont want to create an object with all its properties when there is no need. for example, inside constructor `b` I want to use constructor b method.

```
function a(){
  this.first=function(){
    return 'aaaaaa'
  }
  this.last=function (){
    return 'bbbbb'
  }
}

function b(){
  this.name= //call method last of constructor a.
}    

var person= new b();
console.log(person.name) //bbbbb
```

Note: Constructor a contains two method. So In given example I do not have any use of method first but may required later on. So I don't want to create `new a()`. I just want to call it directly

Comment: You can't do that.  Move the methods to the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to get its function.

1. **create name space**

> ```
> var a={
>   first:function(){
>     return 'aaaaaa'
>   },
>   last:function (){
>     return 'bbbbb'
>   }
> }
>
>
> function b(){
>   this.name= a.last()
> }
> ```

2. **Add methods to prototype property**

> ```
> var a=function(){
> };
> a.prototype.first=function(){
>    return 'aaaaaa'
> };
> a.prototype.last=function (){
>     return 'bbbbb'
> }
> function b(){
>   this.name= a.prototype.last()
> }
> ```

finally this will be same as previous one.

3. **call a() and call its methods directly.(without a())**

Third is call a() which will create "first" & "last" methods which will be function for its context. and then call your method. **But this way is not recommended**.
for ex.

> ```
> function a(){
>     this.first=function(){
>         return 'aaaaaa'
>     }
>     this.last=function (){
>         return 'bbbbb'
>    }
> }
> a()
> function b(){   this.name= last()}    
>
> var person= new b(); console.log(person.name) //bbbbb}}
> ```

Comment: Your first example is not working. When I have removed this. then it is working fine. I Just want to know about your 3 point where you said "call a() and call its methods directly.(without a())",  Can you put some example of that

Comment: @amit, I made changes to answer, please refer it.

Comment: sorry there is no need of this in namespace. sorry for my typo mistake

Answer (score 2):

```
function a(){

}

a.prototype.last=function(){
    return 'bbbb'
}

function b(){
    this.name= a.prototype.last()//call method last of constructor a.
}    

var person= new b();
console.log(person.name) //bbbbb
```

Comment: Your is working well. Just for knowledge what is the difference between assigning a method directly in constructor and adding method using prototype

Comment: Well, here is a good detailed answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784844/setting-javascript-prototype-function-within-object-class-declaration

Answer (score 1):

```
function a(){

  this.first=function(){
    return 'aaaaaa';
  }

  this.last= lastfunc;

}

function b(){
  this.name= lastFunct()
}

var person= new b();
console.log(person.name) //bbbbb

function lastFunct() {
  return 'bbbbb';
}
```

Comment: I know that you are replicating OP answer as close as possible, but might be better to add these functions to the constructor prototype. e.g. b.prototype.name = function..., a.prototype.last = lastfunc, a.prototype.first = function...

Comment: @Patrick I agree, but I'll leave it as is since there is another answere with that solution. It's still valid.

Comment: Agreed. I provided the comment before the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`first` and `last` don't exist until you create an instance of `a`. If those are just static methods, why not use an object?

```
var a = {
  first: function(){
    return 'aaaaaa'
  },
  last: function (){
    return 'bbbbb'
  }
};
```