# JavaScript inner function scope chain?

Tags: javascript, scope

In this example

```
var a = 1;
( function(x) {   
   function inner() {
      alert(a);
      alert(x);
      alert(y); 
   }
   var y = 3;
   inner();
})(2);
```

When does `function inner` get created? during execution time or parsing time of outer anonymous function?

What is in the scope chain of `function inner`?

What is the difference between the execution context and scope chain of `function inner`?

Thanks for enlighting me in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When does function inner get created? during execution time or parsing time of outer anonymous function?

One is created each time the outer function is executed.

> What is in the scope chain of function inner?

When you execute it, that execution gets a variable object (technically the spec calls this the "binding object of the variable environment"); that's backed by the variable object created for the outer function call that created `inner`; that's backed by the global variable object. So:

```
+------------------------------+
| global variable obj          |
+------------------------------+
    ^
    |
   +-----------------------------+
   | variable obj for outer call |
   +-----------------------------+
       ^
       |
      +-----------------------------+
      | variable obj for inner call |
      +-----------------------------+
```

> What is in the execution context of function inner?

Every function call gets its own execution context. I'm not quite sure I understand what's being asked here.

You can read up on all of this stuff (if you're willing to wade through the treacle of turgid prose) in Section 10 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), and in particular [section 10.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3): *"Entering Function Code"*.

Comment: execution context gets created at run time, scope chain gets created at definition time (not sure it is the right term),
my question is: what is the difference between the execution context and scope chain of function inner? What is the process of execution context creation? thx!

Comment: @Ding: Yes, the scope chain is dictated by where the function is defined. You can tell by looking at a function in the source what identifiers are in-scope for it, and where they come from. But functions don't have execution contexts, only *calls* to functions do. The execution context includes the variable object that forms the runtime mechanism of the scope chain, as well as other things, like what the `this` value should be. You clearly have an interest in actually knowing how this stuff works (which is great!) and so I can only say: Read Sect 10 (esp 10.3 & 4) of the spec for details. :-)

Answer (score 10):

The `inner` function gets created just before the anonymous function is executed, by the [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) process.

The [`[[Scope]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2) of `inner` when it's executed contains:

1. The empty Variable Object of `inner` (it's empty because there are no variable/function declarations inside it)
2. The Variable Object of the anonymous function, which contains `x`, `y` and `inner`.
3. The Global Object, that will contain `a` and other properties...

```
    Global (3)          Anonymous VO (2)       inner VO (1)
   ________              ________              ________
  | a = 1  | <--------- | x = 2  | < -------- |        |
  | ...    |            | y = 3  |             ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ 
   ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯             | inner  |
                         ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

**Edit**: To clarify your second question:

> What is the difference between the execution context and scope chain of function inner?

Are two different concepts, an execution context is created just before a piece of code (which [can be](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.2) either global code, function code or eval code) is executed.

I think this might be easier to explain with your code:

```
var a = 1;
(function(x) {        // Step 1
   function inner() {
      alert(a);
      alert(x);
      alert(y); 
   }
   var y = 3;
   inner();           // Step 3
})(2);                // Step 2
```

In the **Step 1**, the anonymous function is [*created*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2), the current scope (only containing the global object) is stored in this moment on the function `[[Scope]]` property.

In the **Step 2**, this anonymous function is executed, a new execution context is created (a [function code execution context](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.2.3)), at this moment a new lexical environment is created (the Variable Object of this function is created), all function argument identifiers (in this case only `x`), identifiers of function declarations (`inner`) and identifiers of variable declarations  (`y`) are bound as non-deletable properties of this new variable object (which is the new lexical scope).

In the **Step 3** the `inner` function is executed, this creates a new execution context, another Variable Object is injected into the scope chain, but in this case since nothing is declared inside `inner` and it doesn't have any formal parameters, it will be just an empty object.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742819/if-the-with-statement-in-javascript-creates-a-new-scope-why-does-the-following/2742849#2742849) answer, the first part I talk about the `with` statement but in the second part it's about functions.

Comment: this thing is really hard to read (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), can you recommend a open source JS engine code? how about V8? thx!

Comment: @Ding, well, IMO reading code would be much more difficult, however I can recommend you the Dmitry Soshnikov [ECMA-262 In Detail Series](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/)...