# Want to pass a variable to node async's map method

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I'm using node async, and I'd like to pass a variable to the method that it uses within the second parameter... e.g:

```
  async.map(submissions, addScore, function(err, submissions) {
    if (submissions) {
      return submissions;
    }
  });
```

I want to pass `userId` along with `addScore` but am not sure how to do this.

`addScore` is my method that I call on every submission and it requires a `userId`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a closure to put the userId into the addScore function scope:

```
var createAddScore = function(userId){
    return function(val){
        // do something with userID and val
    }
}
```

then:

```
async.map(submissions, createAddScore(1), function(err, submissions) {
    if (submissions) {
        return submissions;
    }
});
```

Comment: Not quite working for my case. I modified it a little bit, but I get undefined is not a function. If I take it out of the function closure, it won't even go into my addScore() function. http://pastebin.com/u4AMmSz3 Can you please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to make the `addScore` function the return value of the `createAddScore` function.  That way, you call `createAddScore` passing a `userId`, returning an `addScore` function, and that `userId` is available to the returned function when it is called by async.  See these questions for details about closure's and scope in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858340/javascript-inner-function-scope-chain

Comment: Nice dude thanks. I realized that what was messing me up initially was the additional callback that `map` passes in as the second parameter... so I was doing `return function(submission)` instead of `return function(submission, fn)` within `createAddFunction`, so it wasn't doing it asynchronously thus finishing too soon. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @bob_cobb could you post your final solution? I'm having a similar issue.