# Why is this text effect not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the script from [here](http://i-code.co.uk/javascript/decryptingtext.php) to work on more then one span.

I have tried this, but it seems to overwrite both spans with the same text.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var got;
var chars;

function change(decSpan,encSpan)
{
   var randstring = "";
   var rslength = chars.length - got.length;

   var decrypted = document.getElementById(decSpan);
   var encrypted = document.getElementById(encSpan);

   for(var x=0;x<rslength;x++)
   {
       i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
       randstring += chars.charAt(i);
   }

   if(randstring.charAt(0) == chars.charAt(got.length))
   {
      got += randstring.charAt(0);
      decrypted.innerHTML = got;
   }
   else
   {
      encrypted.innerHTML = randstring;
   }

   if(chars.length > got.length)
   {
  setTimeout("change('"+decSpan+"','"+encSpan+"')", 10);
   }
   else
   {
      encrypted.innerHTML = "";
   }
}
function startdecrypt()
{
   var decodeSpans = ["decoded","decoded2"];
   var encodeSpans = ["encoded","encoded2"];
   for(var z in decodeSpans) 
   {
decSpan = decodeSpans[z];
encSpan = encodeSpans[z];
    var decrypted = document.getElementById(decSpan);
    var encrypted = document.getElementById(encSpan);

    chars = decrypted.innerHTML;
    decrypted.innerHTML = "";
    got = "";
    setTimeout("change('"+decSpan+"','"+encSpan+"')", 10);
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<input type="button" value="go" onClick="javascript:startdecrypt()"><br>
<span id="decoded">Test1</span><span id="encoded"></span><br>
<span id="decoded2">Test2</span><span id="encoded2"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When the button is clicked, the texts change randomly but still use all characters from the original texts. If this is what you want, it works for me. What do you mean by "no working"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that that script uses global javascript variables: `chars` and `got` are set in `startdecrypt` and used later in `change` function. Thus, the next iteration of loop overrides previously set values.

The best solution is probably to include them in js call of `change` function, like you do with ids.

Also, make sure to declare all js variables local to avoid such side-effects: `var got = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit not to have gone through the whole of your code, but it seems you made an unintended Javascript closure, like in this example:

[Javascript closures - variable scope question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273210/javascript-closures-variable-scope-question)

Or, as Nikita put it, global variables, which, when refered to in the `change()` function make a closure. Note that the `var` inside the `for` does not change anything. Javascript does not have block scope.

Note that using `var` inside the loop or declaring `var x` at the top of the function has the same effect. You might want to consider using `let` instead:

[`Let` statemennt from Mozilla Developper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#let_statement)

Closures are hard to understand, especially unintended ones. Ender's answer on the link above has helpful links about how they work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this *should* do what you're looking for:

```
var decodeSpans = ["decoded", "decoded2"];
var encodeSpans = ["encoded","encoded2"];

function encoder(decSpan, encSpan){
    this.encSpan = encSpan;
    this.decSpan = decSpan;
    var got = "";
    var chars = decSpan.innerHTML;
    decSpan.innerHTML = "";
    return (function(){
        var randstring = "";
        var rslength = chars.length - got.length;

        for(var x=0;x<rslength;x++){
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randstring += chars.charAt(i);
        }

        if(randstring.charAt(0) == chars.charAt(got.length)){
            got += randstring.charAt(0);
            decSpan.innerHTML = got;
        }else{
            encSpan.innerHTML = randstring;
        }

        if(chars.length > got.length){
            decSpan.innerHTML = chars;
            encSpan.innerHTML = "";
        }else{
            encSpan.innerHTML = "";
        }
    })();
}

function startdecrypt(){
    for(var z = 0; z < decodeSpans.length; z++){
        decSpan = decodeSpans[z];
        encSpan = encodeSpans[z];
        var decrypted = document.getElementById(decSpan);
        var encrypted = document.getElementById(encSpan);
        encoder(decrypted, encrypted);
    }
}
```

I only read up properly on closures like 2 nights ago, so still trying to put it all into context, so some (constructive) feedback on this solution would be welcome from those who know about these things :)