# Javascript: Passing local variables into a dynamically created function that is a parameter inside another function

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, dynamic-function

I am using a function with the following parameterization (which cannot be changed):

```
my_function(data, callback_function(results, status) {});
```

I need to pass additional information to callback_function that cannot be added to 'data' (which callback_function uses) or 'results' or 'status'.  Specifically this information is the counter of a for loop that the my_function call is in.

To do this I am including a reference to the counter inside the body of callback_function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  var data = 'cannot modify this data';

  my_function(data, function (results, status) { alert(i); });

}
```

Unfortunately the final value of i (9 in this case) is being printed 10 times.  The intended behavior is for each value of i in the loop (0 through 9) to be printed.

Is it possible for dynamic functions to access variables outside of their scope but within the scope that they are defined?

Comment: your already using closures,i think.. and the value 9 is a reference to i -- which is changed to 9 at the end of the loop and hence prints 9 -- always!!

Comment: if your trying to define the myfunction with the values provided by `i` and later  trying to call it -- its a closure..!!.. its accessing the reference to i..

Comment: @VivekChandra The second part of my code is the actual call to my_function, not the definition.  And I don't believe my_function is a closure since i is not being passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Vivek: integers are no reference types in JS. Plus, he is not creating a closure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a [**closure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) that contains the value of `i` *at the time where the anonymous function is created*. You can use a wrapper function for that:

```
function createClosure(x, func) {
  return function(results, status) { func(x, results, status); }
}

/* ... */

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var data = 'cannot modify this data';
  my_function(data, createClosure(i, function(i, results, status) { 
    alert(i);
    alert(results);
    alert(status);
  }));
}
```

Or if you want to be short, you can create the closure in place:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var data = 'cannot modify this data';
  my_function(data, (function(i) {
    return function (results, status) { 
      alert(i); 
    }
  })(i));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change or use the parameters for the callback_function that is being passed as a parameter.

Comment: @user1193461: I don't understand? Maybe you want to define the callback inside the loop, in that case you need an additional layer of indirection... I updated the code, maybe it's more helpful now.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot modify the parameters of my_function or the parameters of callback_function.  Your callback 'createClosure' is no longer using the required 'results' and 'status' parameters.

Comment: @user1193461: Have you actually tried it? `createClosure` is *NOT* the callback function! It merely creates a callback function for you and returns it. I added another sample which does the same, but in a more convulted way. Maybe you like it better.

Comment: My apologies, both of those solutions do work.  Could you please explain the following syntax from solution 2:

(function(i) { //code })(i)

Comment: I will go with this solution due to browser compatibility.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Using that you can *bind* a function to certain parameters. With that in place, your code will look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  var data = 'cannot modify this data';

  function callback(iValue, results, status) { alert(iValue); }
  my_function(data, callback.bind(null, i)); // |null| since you don't seem to need any specific |this|.

}
```

Comment: I like this as well.  Is .bind supported on non-Mozilla browsers?

Comment: It is supported on Chrome 18 (perhaps eariler. It is V8-based, so not sure about Safari/JSC) as well. At the very least, the link to MDN I gave above contains an implementation for browsers that do not support this method.

Comment: It appears .bind does not work on Safari for iPhone.  At least this example doesn't.  And I would like to avoid adding fallback code if possible.  I hope Apple resolves this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

var data = 'cannot modify this data';

my_function(data, function (results, status) { 
 alert( 
  function(value){ 
    return value;
    }(i);
 )
}   //function (results, status)  ends here
);  // myfunction ends here..

}
```

Not tested it,but .. try it.. hope it works..

Check this link -> [Javascript closures - variable scope question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273210/javascript-closures-variable-scope-question)  for a better understanding of what you are doing..

Comment: Could you explain what is happening with x here:

function(value) { return value; } (x);

Comment: `function(value) {...}` is an anonymous function expression. Treat it as an ordinary function but without a name. You can assign it (e.g. `window.onerror = function(e) { /* handle e */ }` which will be invoked internally as `window.onerror()`) or you can invoke it directly, like in the case above. What happens is the `value` parameter receives the value of `x`. That is it.

Comment: I see, so (x) is treated as an argument for 'function' in much the same way that command-line arguments are handled.  Is there a name for this way of passing values into functions?

Comment: You might want to check the [ECMA-262 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) but I don't see much difference between `fn(x)` and `function(param) {...}(x)`, the latter case just invokes the function directly rather than by reference.